# How to save image in node.js without any libs for parsing and saving files, which came from client form (multipart/form-data)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, express, encoding

I have a simple form on my client (SSR, but doesn't matter)

```
<form method="post" action="/" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input type="file" name="avatar">
   <button type="submit"></button>
</form>
```

So

I know how to copy an existing file doing like this

```
const image = fs.readFileSync('image.jpg');
fs.writeFile('imageClone.jpg', image, ()=> {
   console.log('done)
});
```

Or just with getting image base64 code (from a converter for example) and then create it from buffer

```
const uri = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABQAAAAUCAYAAACNiR0"
   + "NAAAAKElEQVQ4jWNgYGD4Twzu6FhFFGYYNXDUwGFpIAk2E4dHDRw1cDgaCAASFOffhEIO"
   + "3gAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==";

const base64Data = uri.split(',')[1];
const buffer = Buffer.from(base64Data, 'base64');

fs.writeFile('image.png', buffer, ()=> {
   console.log('done')
});
```

So the question is how to do it with file, which i get from that simple form? How to parse it correctly?
I can do that using multer, but i want to handle it without multer or its analogs.

This doesn't work because i get some extra data, but i dont know to to parse it and what encoding should i use to do it clearly

```
app.post("/", (req, res) => {
   req.setEncoding('base64')
   let body = '';

  req.on("data", (data) => {
     console.log(data)
     body += data;
  });
  req.on("end", () => {
     const buffer = Buffer.from(body, "base64");

     fs.writeFileSync("test.jpg", buffer);
  });
});
```

I am a newbee, so i am probably doing something very strange on the last one pice of code.
Some examplese were token from some answerses here, i got something, but cant solve this case.

Answer (score 0):

The format of a multipart HTTP stream is a bit complicated because unlike regular HTTP request or response a multipart HTTP streams consist of multiple HTTP "packets".

Generally, the structure of a multipart stream looks like this:

```
HTTP headers...
two newlines (\n\n or \r\n\r\n) indicating end of headers

content
Boundary string...
HTTP headers...
two newlines (\n\n or \r\n\r\n) indicating end of headers

content
Boundary string...
HTTP headers...
two newlines (\n\n or \r\n\r\n) indicating end of headers

content

etc.
```

Each form item will have its own HTTP "packet" effectively splitting the single HTTP response into multiple parts (hence multipart). This is actually the same protocol/mechanism/format that emails use to attach files. The RFC for multipart constantly refer to the RFCs that define email.

For multipart specifically there are two HTTP headers that concern us:

- Content-type

  If content-type is set to multipart/form-data this header will also define the boundary string.
- Content-disposition

  This specifies metadata for each "part" such as the filename etc.

The following is an example HTTP request that is formatted as multipart:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8000
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=s2sw1s2ed2edee22qdd2e
Content-Length: 199

s2sw1s2ed2edee22qdd2e
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="text"

text foo
s2sw1s2ed2edee22qdd2e
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file1"; filename="a.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain

Hello World
```

The above example demonstrates the submission of a form with an input and a file selector. The input's name is "text" and the file selector's name is "file1" so the HTML would have been something like:

```
<form action="http://localhost:8000" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <p><input type="text" name="text">
  <p><input type="file" name="file1">
  <p><button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Express will handle most of the data in the first header. What express won't do is handle the rest. So your response body is literally:

```
s2sw1s2ed2edee22qdd2e
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="text"

text foo
s2sw1s2ed2edee22qdd2e
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file1"; filename="a.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain

Hello World
```

As you can see, the format of multipart is kind of complicated but not too hard to figure out. You can write your own middleware to parse it or ideally you'd use something like [multiparty](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multiparty) or [formidable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/formidable) to do it because parsing this is not trivial.